# LEFT JOIN on 3 tables to get a value

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to create an new interface for a database but I don't know how to do what I want.
I have 3 tables :

```
- table1(id1, time, ...)
id11 ..
id12 ..
id13 ..

- table2(id2, price, ...)
id21 ..
id22 ..
id23 ..

- table1_table2(#id1, #id2, value)
id11, id22, 6
id11, id23, 10
id13, id22, 5
```

So I want to have something like this :

```
id11, id21, 0
id11, id22, 6
id11, id23, 10
id12, id21, 0
id12, id22, 0
id12, id23, 0
id13, id21, 0
id13, id22, 5
id13, id23, 0
```

I've tried lots of requests but nothing efficient..
Please, help me ^^

EDIT : I'm using Access ( :'( ) 2007, and apparently, it doesn't support CROSS JOIN... 
I tried to use this : http://blog.jooq.org/2014/02/12/no-cross-join-in-ms-access/
but still have a syntax error on the JOIN or the FROM..

EDIT 2 : Here is my query (I'm french, so don't take care of names please ^^)

```
SELECT Chantier.id_chantier, Indicateur.id_indicateur, Indicateur_chantier.valeur
       FROM ((Chantier INNER JOIN Indicateur ON (Chantier.id_chantier*0 =    Indicateur.id_indicateur*0))
       LEFT JOIN Indicateur_chantier ON ( (Chantier.id_chantier = Indicateur_chantier.id_chantier) 
       AND (Indicateur.id_indicateur = Indicateur_chantier.id_indicateur) ) )
```

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server, MySQL...?

Comment: Looks like you want a `CROSS JOIN` between the first 2 tables. That could result in a large amount of data!

Comment: I know but this what I want ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first cross join table1 and table2 to produce their Cartesian product and the left join to get the values where exist :

```
 SELECT t1.id1,t2.id2,ISNULL(t12.value,0)
 FROM table1 t1
 CROSS JOIN table2 t2
 LEFT JOIN table1_table2  t12 on t12.id1=t.id1 and t12.id2=t2.id2
```

Finally use ISNULL to replace null values with zeros.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't know CROSS JOIN even exist !

Answer (score 1):

Answer may vary by database, this works in SQL Server, you need a `CROSS JOIN` to get every combination of `table1` and `table2`, then a `LEFT JOIN` to return pairs with values:

```
SELECT a.id1, b.id2, COALESCE(c.value,0)
FROM table1 a
CROSS JOIN table2 b
LEFT JOIN table3 c
  ON a.id1 = c.id1
 AND b.id2 = c.id2
```

Pairs without values would return `NULL`, so you can use `COALESCE()` to return 0 instead.

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9e85fd/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say that Access "doesn't support CROSS JOIN". While it is true that Access SQL does not support

```sql
... FROM tableX CROSS JOIN tableY ...
```

you can perform a cross join in Access by simply using

```sql
... FROM tableX, tableY ...
```

In your case,

```sql
SELECT
    crossjoin.id1,
    crossjoin.id2,
    Nz(table1_table2.value, 0) AS [value]
FROM
    (
        SELECT table1.id1, table2.id2
        FROM table1, table2
    ) AS crossjoin
    LEFT JOIN
    table1_table2
        ON table1_table2.id1 = crossjoin.id1
            AND table1_table2.id2 = crossjoin.id2
ORDER BY crossjoin.id1, crossjoin.id2
```